# Adding Swedll32.dll to VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm

I am trying to add `swedll32.dll` as reference into visual studio 2010 through add Reference in my project.

But it's giving an error message:

```
reference can not be added, please make sure that the file is accesible,
and that is a valid assembly or com component
```

Can anybody help me in adding this `dll` to visual studio?

Comment: It's likely that the DLL is a native (unmanaged) DLL, and if so you can't add it as a reference to a .NET project. You will need to use P/Invoke instead.

Comment: The project already gives [string hints](http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc379890551) on how to use it.  VB5 is very old, you have to write the .NET version of these declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The dll is a native, unmanaged dll. The development started 1997, 4 years before `.NET` even became available. You will need to find a way to either `PInvoke` the methods or use a programming language better suited to interface with it like `C`or `C++`.

You may want to start reading about [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is a way to import native dlls to call from managed code. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a good starting point.